# How do struct module works in kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have written a interrupt driver linux version 3.8 for learning. I am using some gpio apis such as

```
gpio_request(gpioButton, "mypreciousss");       // Set up the gpioButton
```

When I saw inside this gpio_request it is using

```
if (!try_module_get(chip->owner))
```

here  **chip->owner** is a **struct module** type variable.

**gpio_request** was the first function in my init function, and I did nothing to create **struct module**.
So how **try_module_get** can use one?

Comment: The question is not written in English, please find someone to translate. Guessing what you are asking I can assume that you didn't get the second  example in your post. This is basically reference counting. When GPIO line is requested the removal of controller driver is forbidden.

Comment: are you blind or plain dumb?

Answer (score 0):

Here I am pasting the code snippet from function `gpio_request()` (linux 3.8)

```
     desc = &gpio_desc[gpio];
     chip = desc->chip;
     if (chip == NULL)
            goto done;

     if (!try_module_get(chip->owner))
             goto done;
```

Here, they are taking descriptor corresponding to passed GPIO, and that descriptor structure is used for further updates.